# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 to an HP system?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, hp

Okay, so this has probably been asked time and time again but I genuinely need some advice.

So, my old computer ended up taking some damage and I decided to replace it since it likely would've cost more to repair than it would've to replace. I settled for the HP Pavilion x360 (which I got today) and decided to use the same USB stick I had used to install Ubuntu on my old system.

I've disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS and set the boot order so it would boot into the USB first and I was met with a mostly blank screen that read "incompatible license" "Aborted. Press any key to exit." and was brought to the Boot Manager.

Any tips?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS were you trying to install?  Does it have HWE or hardware enablement in use (meaning a later kernel & software stack is in use) or the original release version?  I'm assuming it was Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop ; but it's better if you're specific.

Comment: I'm honestly not entirely sure. How would I check for something like that?

Comment: HWE is found in Ubuntu 18.04.2 and above (the higher .x number meaning a later stack).  If it's running (in 'live' mode) a `uname -r` will give the kernel in use; 18.04 (& 18.04.1) came with 4.15; where as 18.04.2 provided 4.18, 18.04.3 provided 5.0 (ie. later kernel meaning later kernel modules or support for newer devices).  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: Okay, so I ran the command and it came back with "4.15.0-72-generic" (will probably edit the post to add that information.)

Comment: My guess is that you've got Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. As your HP device is pretty new I'd recommend trying Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with its newer software stack.  (far less effort than anything else I can think of)

Comment: It may be better to download the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04.3 from the Ubuntu site. You may also want to try version 19.10.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks a bunch!